# Is there any way to get domain users under google enterprise apps domain using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: google-apps, google-provisioning-api, google-admin-sdk

Google Provisioning APIs use Google data protocol which requires admin userid and password. I looking for something like Google drive APIs so that I can use authority delegated service account to fetch entreprise info also. Idea is to avoid asking Admin credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Provisioning APIs [support OAuth](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/auth) just fine. However, you should probably use the brand new [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk) which also supports the newer Google API similar to Drive SDK.